# C++ Smallest common divisor rewrite

Tags: c++, math

I made a function that returns the smallest common divisor of 2 numbers.

```
int check (int a, int b)
{
 int i = 2; //every number is divisible by 1
   begin:
    if ((a % i == 0) && (b%i == 0)) //i must be divisible by both numbers
      {
         return i;
      }
    else
      {
          i++;
          goto begin;
      }
}
```

However, I'm using the much-advised-against goto, so I was wondering how this could be rewritten using a *for* or *while* loop.

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your code has a bug. A=3 b=5 Will do an endless loop

Comment: @Jerome My computer is very fast. It evaluates your endless loop in 18 seconds.

Comment: @CodeInChaos ; result is -1 ? Do not Know if perf is an issue here ;-)

Comment: Smallest?? Normally one is interested in the greatest common divisor (GCD) and the least common multiple (LCM).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a and b are co-prime (gcd=1) your algorithm will only terminate once i has overflowed and reached -1. i.e. after 4 billion iterations.

And even if this is not the case your algorithm is slow(linear in gcd(a,b)). You should look into the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) which is much faster.

Your code in rewritten form(termination problem not fixed) so it's equivalent to your old code:

```
int check (int a, int b)
{
 int i = 2; //every number is divisible by 1
   while(!((a % i == 0) && (b%i == 0)))//i must be divisible by both numbers
   {
      i++;
   } 
   return i;
}
```

Rewritten into a for loop that terminates once it's clear that gcd==1

```
int check (int a, int b)
{
  for(int i=2;i<=Math.Min(a,b);i++)
  {
    if((a % i == 0) && (b%i == 0))
      return i;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: infinite loop in case of both a and b are prime numbers.

Comment: @GregS I only edited that in while Krtek was posting is comment.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but 'infinite loop' is way more understandable for someone asking help about a while loop than integer overflow  ;). And using i < min(a, b) as an other stopping condition while easily solve this problem.

Comment: Makes me wonder how much code in the production world actually relies (accidently) on integer overflow to terminate. Bob: "Your code sure runs slow for certain numbers". Bill: "Yeah, but it works, so I'm not even going to look at it".

Comment: There's a problem in the code - I think you meant (!(a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)). It's also easier to formulate as (a % i != 0 || b % i != 0).

Comment: At first I thought it's terminate at 1, but when actually running `check(3,5)` returned -1. @Olli fixed.

Comment: Also, how do you get the lowest common divisor > 1 using the Euclidean algorithm? Factoring the resulting gcd, or is there a better way? Of course factoring a single smaller number is already much easier than factoring two large ones.

Comment: @Olli good question. But probably that's the best you can do.

Comment: And one more thing: the code that you say is equivalent still isn't because you didn't fix the logical problem there.

Comment: @Olli Can you elaborate on why the termination problem isn't in the original code? The original code runs until it reaches -1, i.e. it only terminates thanks to an int-overflow. And I think my `while` code reproduces the problem exactly.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean the termination problem, rephrased my last comment. And seems you added the extra set of parentheses too in your last edit, so now it is correct.

Comment: I know it doesn't take prime numbers into account, I only wanted to get the "simple" part right. Next time I should specify that. Thanks to all anyway!

Comment: @rrr The number don't need to be prime for it to fail. It's enough that they are co-prime. for example `check(4,9)` will exhibit the problem too. And neither 4 not 9 is prime.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, so basically numbers that do not have a common divisor smaller than or equal to the biggest number of the two, right? Anyway this question was really more about the implementation of the loop than the correctness of the function itself.

Comment: Euclidean algorithm returns the *greatest* common divisor, whereas this guy wants the *smallest* common divisor.

Comment: Factoring the gcd is probably still the fastest method to find the smallest common divisor.

Answer (score 1):

```
int check (int a, int b)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < min(a,b); i++)
        if ((a % i == 0) && (b%i == 0)) //i must be divisible by both numbers
            return i;
    return 1;
}
```

Where `min()`... well, you figure it...

Comment: You forgot the `return 1` case for when the loop doesn't find any common divisior. Your current code probably won't compile with "Not all codepaths return a value".

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i < min(a, b)) {
     ...
}
```

Comes to mind... As soon as i is greater than a or b, there's no point in going further.

There's another problem in your code, if a and b are both prime, it will be an infinite loop ;)

EDIT : it is really important to understand that you can't use the divisibility as a stopping condition, otherwise this can lead to an infinite loop when both numbers are prime, or if they don't have a common divisor.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 2; (a % i != 0) || (b%i != 0); ++i)
{
    if( i > a || i > b)//a and b are prime
        return 1;
}
return i;
```

Comment: infinite loop if a and b are both prime numbers.